# argox r 400plus ribbom and ready leed blink

Tags: printing, ribbon

Installed, reinstalled, calibrated, I reset and the lights continue to flash at the same time. What can it be? Prints and once they start flashing, I have to reboot to be able to print again.

Answer (score 0):

I changed thermal transfer to direct transfer. Now work perfectly!